# Why have my Task Manager Performance tab mini-graphs turned into dots?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1117561/what-is-the-secondary-cpu-usage-graph-line-in-the-windows-10-task-manager), you can see the Task Manager showing mini-graphs for all the metrics on the left (ignore the right arrow; that's germane to the question at the above URL).

[image: mini graphs]

Occasionally, Task Manager only shows me dots.

[image: dots]

How do I get the mini-graphs back?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Right-Click the left pane where the graphs should be, and select "Show graphs"

[image: Show graphs context dropdown shown]